# What is the type of pavement defect and how to address the issue?

Tags: pavement

Attached image is from a very high water table and high salinity area. What is the type of pavement defect and how to address the issue?[image: high salinity and water table area]

Comment: What area of the world is this? And what type of pavement is it?  Both of those details will be very helpful for people who are trying to answer your question.

Comment: It's called blistering, and there are a lot of tech papers about it.

Answer (score 1):

My reputation is to low to comment but that looks like frost heave to me, does this area experience freezing temperatures?

If it is frost-heave the answer is generally proper drainage and replacing the susceptible materials under the pavement.

**EDIT:**
As suggested by [Phil Sweet](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/users/12754/phil-sweet) this could also be blistering.
There are several types of blistering and the remediation depends on the underlying cause. Blistering can be caused by a number of factors and would require inspection by a professional to determine the cause.

Comment: The palm tree on the right suggests not.

Comment: @PhilSweet actually many palm tree species can handle freezing temperatures. Also an area that seldom experiences freezing temperatures is less likely to consider frost heave when constructing roads.